# How to modify a line in a file with Erlang OTP module

Tags: file-io, erlang

I got a big file and I would like to replace the first line with other content.
When I use `{ok, IoDev} = file:open("/root/FileName", [write, raw, binary])`, the whole content is removed.

But when I use `{ok, IoDev} = file:open("/root/FileName", [append, raw, binary])` and `file:pwrite(S, {bof,0}, <<"new content\n">>)`, I got the result `{error, badarg}`.

If I set Location to 0: `file:pwrite(S, 0, <<"new content\n">>)`, the string is appended at tail of the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be confused with the actual file API.

[`file:open/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#open-2) will truncate the file if you pass `[write, raw, binary]`as you do:

> (about `write` mode): The file is opened for writing. It is created if it does not exist. If the file exists, and if `write` is not combined with `read`, the file will be truncated.

So you need to pass either `[write, read]` or `[write, append]` as documented.

[`file:pwrite/3`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#pwrite-3) also works exactly as documented. It allows you to write at a given position in the file. In particular, you cannot pass `{bof, 0}` as second argument since you opened the file in raw mode:

> If `IoDevice` has been opened in raw mode, some restrictions apply: `Location` is only allowed to be an integer; and the current position of the file is undefined after the operation.

The following sample code shows how they work:

```
ok = file:write_file("/tmp/file", "This is line 1.\nThis is line 2.\n"),
{ok, F} = file:open("/tmp/file", [read, write, raw, binary]),
ok = file:pwrite(F, 0, <<"This is line A.\n">>),
ok = file:close(F),
{ok, Content} = file:read_file("/tmp/file"),
io:put_chars(Content),
ok = file:delete("/tmp/file").
```

It will output:

```
This is line A.
This is line 2.
```

This works because text `"This is line A.\n"` is exactly as long as `"This is line 1.\n"`. It does not really replace the line, but just bytes. If you need to replace the first line with content that has a different length, you need to rewrite the whole content of the file. A common approach is indeed to write a new file and swap them eventually. If the file is small enough, however, you can read it entirely in memory and rewrite it. `file:read_file/1` and `file:write_file/2` would work:

```
replace_first_line(Path, NewLine) ->
    {ok, Content} = file:read_file(Path),
    [FirstLine | Tail] = binary:split(Content, <<"\n">>),
    NewContent = [NewLine, <<"\n">> | Tail],
    ok = file:write_file(Path, NewContent).
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not related to erlang but rather general file operations.

Replacing a line in a file requires to rewrite the file in a whole. The easiest way to do so would be to write all the new content in a new file and then to move the file.